# RKObject subclassing

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, restkit

I've just started using RestKit, and got an issue when trying to create RKObject subclass; apparently, such class is not found, but this example http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/restkit_ios-sdk/ shows how to make it. I installed it and it seems to be working ok.

So I am wondering whether that class was removed and there is an alternative or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, RKObject was removed. [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/restkit/ACaAQdWl-po) is an answer to the same question.